# Refactoring PostgreSQL connection from index.js into a Controller : How to pass PgClient to the Controller?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, ecmascript-6

I'm refactoring the following code :

```
require('dotenv').config();

// Express App Setup
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const uuid = require('uuid/v4');

// Config
const config = require('./config');

// Initialization
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Postgres client
const { Pool } = require('pg');
const pgClient = new Pool({
  user: config.pgUser,
  host: config.pgHost,
  database: config.pgDatabase,
  password: config.pgPassword,
  port: config.pgPort
});
pgClient.on('error', () => console.log('Lost Postgres connection'));

pgClient
  .query(
    `
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items (
    id uuid,
    item_name TEXT NOT NUll,
    complete BOOLEAN DEFAULT false,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
  )
`
  )
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

// Express route handlers
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Working!');
});

// Get all to do list items
app.get('/v1/items', async (req, res) => {
 ...
});

// Get a single todo item
app.get('/v1/items', async (req, res) => {
 ...
});

// Create a todo item
app.post('/v1/items', async (req, res) => {
 ...
});

// Update a todo item
app.put('/v1/items/:id', async (req, res) => {
 ...
});

// Delete a todo item
app.delete('/v1/items/:id', async (req, res) => {
 ..
});

// Server
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

Into a controller & routes usage , as follows :

New index.js :

```
require('dotenv').config();
const itemRoutes = require('./routes/itemRoutes');

// Express App Setup
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const uuid = require('uuid/v4');

// Config
const config = require('./config');

// Initialization
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Postgres client
const {Pool} = require('pg');
const pgClient = new Pool({
  user: config.pgUser,
  host: config.pgHost,
  database: config.pgDatabase,
  password: config.pgPassword,
  port: config.pgPort,
});
pgClient.on('error', () => console.log('Lost Postgres connection'));

pgClient
  .query(
    `
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items (
    id uuid,
    item_name TEXT NOT NUll,
    complete BOOLEAN DEFAULT false,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
  )
`
  )
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

// Express route handlers
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Working!');
});

// middlewares
app.use('/v1', itemRoutes);

// Server
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

**New itemRoutes.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const {
  createItem,
  getSingleItem,
  getAllItems,
  updateItem,
  deleteItem,
} = require('../controllers/item');

router.get('/items', createItem);
router.get('/items', getSingleItem);
router.post('/items', getAllItems);
router.put('/items/:id', updateItem);
router.delete('/items/:id', deleteItem);

module.exports = router;
```

New Controller - The Controller uses the PgClient:

```
exports.getAllItems = async (req, res) => {
 ...
};

exports.getSingleItem = async (req, res) => {
 ...
};

exports.createItem = async (req, res) => {
 ...
};

exports.updateItem = async (req, res) => {
 ...
};

exports.deleteItem = async (req, res) => {
 ...
};
```

The `PgClient` is created in the Index.js.
The problem is , how can I pass the `PgClient` to a controller  , without creating a new instance of the PgClient every time ?

Comment: a) just export it, and import it in the controller module b) make the controller a factory function and pass it by argument c) use an express middleware to put it in the request context

Comment: Btw, your `pgClient`  is not a client but a pool. You really should actually create a client (from that pool) for each request.